# Using EnumSet or EnumMap on arbitrary keys

Tags: java, performance, enums

We know that `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` are faster than `HashSet`/`HashMap` due to the power of bit manipulation. But are we actually harnessing the true power of `EnumSet`/`EnumMap` when it really matters? If we have a set of millions of record and we want to find out if some object is present in that set or not, can we take advantage of `EnumSet`'s speed?

I checked around but haven't found anything discussing this. Everywhere the usual stuff is found i.e. because `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` uses a predefined set of keys lookups on small collections are very fast. I know enums are compile-time constants but can we have best of both worlds - an `EnumSet`-like data structure without needing enums as keys?

Comment: doing a lookup on small collection of value hardly matters due to difference in few millisecs - it will matter if you do this millions of times

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: No, you can't really get anything as good as EnumSet or EnumMap with arbitrary elements, but the benefits can be worthwhile even with small lists of constants for frequent operations that should be very cheap.

Comment: Reframing my question => Can we use enumset/enummap as usual hashset/hasmap so we can dump say millions of data on it at runtime and then do lookup based on the key. Believing if we can do that then  actually we are harnessing the true power of enumset/enummap especially if we are doing this activity several times.

Comment: @Avis: no, not really.  HashSet and HashMap are pretty much as good as possible for arbitrary runtime data.

Comment: @Avis I edited your question to be more clear, if I misunderstood your point at all feel free to correct or revert my changes.

Comment: @Avis try not to think about it in terms of "harnessing the true power of enumset/enummap" - these classes are just marginal optimizations, there's no "true power" going "unharnessed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting insight; the short answer is no, but your question is exploring some good data-structure design concepts which I'll try to discuss.

First, lets talk about `HashMap` (`HashSet` uses a `HashMap` internally, so they share most behavior); a hash-based data structure is powerful because it is fast and general.  It's fast (i.e. approximately `O(1)`) because we can find the key we're looking for with a very small number of computations.  Roughly, we have an array of lists of keys, convert the key to an integer index into that array, then look through the associated list for the key.  As the mapping gets bigger, the backing array is repeatedly resized to hold more lists.  Assuming the lists are evenly distributed, this lookup is *very* fast.  And because this works for any generic object (that has a proper `.hashcode()` and `.equals()`) it's useful for just about any application.

Enums have several interesting properties, but for the purpose of efficient lookup we only care about two of them - they're generally small, and they have a fixed number of values.  Because of this, we can do better than `HashMap`; specifically, we can map every possible value to a unique integer, meaning we don't need to compute a hash, and we don't need to worry about hashes colliding.  So `EnumMap` simply stores an array of the same size as the enum and looks up directly into it:

```
// From Java 7's EnumMap
public V get(Object key) {
    return (isValidKey(key) ?
            unmaskNull(vals[((Enum)key).ordinal()]) : null);
}
```

Stripping away some of the required `Map` sanity checks, it's simply:

```
return vals[key.ordinal()];
```

Note that this is *conceptually* no different than a standard `HashMap`, it's simply avoiding a few computations.  `EnumSet` is a little more clever, using the bits in one or more `long`s to represent array indices, but functionally it's no different than the `EnumMap` case - we allocate enough slots to cover all possible enum values and can use their integer `.ordinal()` rather than compute a hash.

So how much faster than `HashMap` is `EnumMap`?  It's clearly faster, but in truth it's not *that* much faster.  `HashMap` is already a very efficient data structure, so any optimization on it will only yield marginally better results.  In particular, both `HashMap` and `EnumMap` are asymptotically the same speed (`O(1)`), meaning as they get bigger, they behave equally well.  This is the primary reason why there isn't a more general data-structure like `EnumMap` - because it wouldn't be worth the effort relative to `HashMap`.

The second reason we don't want a more general "`FiniteKeysMap`" is it would make our lives as users more complicated, which would be worthwhile if it were a marked speed increase, but since it's not would just be a hassle.  We would have to define an interface (and probably also a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29)) for any type that could be a key in this map.  The interface would need to provide a guarantee that every unique instance returns a unique hashcode in the range `[0-n)`, and also provide a way for the map to get `n` and potentially all `n` elements.  Those last two operations would be better as static methods, but since we can't define static methods in an interface, they'd have to either be passed in directly to every map we create, or a separate factory object with this information would have to exist and be passed to the map/set at construction.  Because enums are part of the language, they get all of those benefits for free, meaning there's no such cost for end-user programmers to need to take advantage of.

Furthermore, it would be very easy to make mistakes with this interface; say you have a type that has exactly `100,000` unique values.  Should it implement our interface?  It *could*.  But you'd likely actually be shooting yourself in the foot.  This would eat up a lot of unnecessary memory, since our `FiniteKeysMap` would allocate a new `100,000` length array to represent even an empty map.  Generally speaking, that sort of wasted space is not worth the marginal improvement such a data structure would provide.

In short, while your idea is possible, it is not practical.  `HashMap` is so efficient that attempting to create a separate data structure for a very limited number of cases would add far more complexity than value.

---

For the specific case of faster `.contains()` checks, you might like [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  It's a set-like data structure that very efficiently stores very large sets, with the condition that it may sometimes incorrectly say an element is in the set when it is not (but not the other way around - if it says an element isn't in the set, it's definitely not).  [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a nice [`BloomFilter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html) implementation.

Comment: `EnumMap` is not only about faster lookup, but also about faster inserts and memory efficiency. There is no need to change the size of the backing array during inserts, and the backing array is of type `Object[]`, which is (a little bit) smaller than the `HashMap`'s `Entry[]`.

Comment: @L.Möller thanks; by "lookups" in my answer, I meant essentially any operation on a set/map, since inserts and removals also require the lookup behaviour I describe.  It's true there's no need to change the size of the backing array, but this can be a cure worse than the illness for large enough enums / other fixed-size types, particularly since you can just instantiate a `HashMap` with a large enough backing array if you know the contents ahead of time.  It's a great feature for `EnumMap`, but would likely be problematic in a `FiniteKeysMap`.

Comment: Thanks dimo414 for compiling such a nice note around the topic and balancing all points very precisely. I totally agree with your points. Cheers.